# What does `_ = something` mean?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.2

I found the following code in my colleague's code.
What does this mean?
 `headerView` and `operateBar` are subclasses of `UIView`.
**IMPORTANNT**: The following code is not part of the `if` statement.
And the `headerView` and `operateBar` are not lazy properties that need to be initialized.

```
_ = self.headerView
_ = self.operateBar
```

Comment: alternative for check against `null` value

Comment: @RatulSharker, no it isn't

Comment: please explain @user28434

Comment: so you are complaining about `nil` & `null`. @user28434

Comment: Mostly i see this portion of code within a `if` statement. Only `_ = self.headerView` has no meaning in it.

Comment: Good to know another one single usage of this syntax. But in that case `self.headerView` would suffice, right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185051/discussion-between-user28434-and-ratul-sharker).

Comment: I distinctly remember in one of the Stanford courses, where the lecturer mentions that _ basically, means that you're telling Swift that you are aware you have not names the variable appropriately but are obligated to return sometime in future and rename it properly. Your colleague probably had a proper name there. But upon seeing that the variable was not used further for any manipulation/calculation, Swift might have encouraged him to change it to _ which he did and forgot about. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

If you see it as a part of `if` statement it checks if `headerView` or `operateBar` is not nil. So this:

```
if let _ = self.headerView {
    //some code
}
```

is equivalent of:

```
if self.headerView != nil {
    //some code
}
```

Comment: @user28434 good point forgot about `let`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: And still, it's `if let` performing `nil` check, `_` here is not related to any checks, it just shows that you don't care about value of `self.headerView`. And latter here is more preferable.